Ubuntu Boot Delay on Lenovo Legion (Intel i7-14650HX, NVIDIA RTX 4060)
I recently installed Ubuntu on my Lenovo Legion laptop with the following specs:
CPU: Intel Core i7-14650HX (16 cores, 24 threads, 2.2–5.2 GHz)
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4060 (8GB GDDR6)
When I power on the laptop, I see the Lenovo Legion logo followed by the Ubuntu logo, but the screen freezes for 1–2 minutes before reaching the welcome/login page. This delay is consistent every time I boot.
I tried:

Updated all packages using sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade.
Installed the latest NVIDIA drivers (nvidia-driver-560).
Disabled Secure Boot in the BIOS.

Is this behavior normal on high-performance laptops like mine, or could it be related to the hybrid graphics (Intel + NVIDIA)? How can I optimize the boot time and get rid of this delay?

